# Reinstalling SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

I am installing SQL Server 2017 on my laptop

I already have SQL Server 2008 Express

I downloaded and installed SQL Server 2017 Developer but when i tried to connect to it the instance i created did not exist for some reason

So I decided to uninstall 2017 and reinstall the express 2017

i uninstalled it

but when i try to reinstall 2017 i get this error

```
unable to install sql server (setup.exe) exit code 1638
```

[image]

I googled and look at other questions and i found that the reason behind this error is that 2017 is already installed

checked Control Panel uninstall

and i found this

[image]

when I try to uninstall it i get this

[image]

then this error

[image]

what am i doing wrong

how to install any instance of SQL 2017??

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10

Comment: I suggest you reboot and try installing SQL 2017 Developer again. The 1638 error code during the Express install indicates setup thinks the product is already installed. Developer should have worked if you selected the database engine component.

Comment: I tried that, same error :(